# Java printing unicode characters in multidimensional arrays in columns + rows?

Tags: java

I have a small project to complete on my course but I'm a little stuck on solving this, basically I need to print the unicode characters in a multidimensional array to a table, 12 rows and 5 columns. So far I have this:

```
public class MultiArrTest {
    public static void main(String[] args0) {
     char[][] uc = new char[12][5];
     int x = 64;

      for (int i = 0; i < uc.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < uc[i].length; j++) {
            uc[i][j] = (char) x++;

            System.out.print(uc[i][j] + " ");

            System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This prints the unicode but only in one column, I feel a bit silly here but could anyone give me a suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `System.out.println();` outside the second `for-loop` and inside the first one, just after the `for-loop`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < uc.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < uc[i].length; j++) {
        uc[i][j] = (char) x++;
        System.out.print(uc[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
 }
```